# Different views using same controller in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, code-reuse, sti

In my Rails application I have a STI where my Super Class is Order and two other sub class (Payment and Subscription) that inherits from Order. This two children class just initialize some Order's attributes with specific values, different views but same controllers methods.

Which is the best approach to maximilize the code reuse in that case? Nowadays I'm repeating controllers and some views codes.

How can I use the same Controller (OrdersControllers) for enherited models?

Comment: You can use any model in any controller, so there is nothing from stopping you doing something like `@payments = Payment.all` in the orders controller, and then using `@payments` in the views. If you give me an example with code I might be able to elaborate a bit.

Comment: I know I can do `@payments = Payment.all` but would be better have something like `@resource = Resource.all` where Resource is the specific class (Subscription or Payment) that is calling the controller, in consequence do the correct redirect/render views...

Comment: ah I see, well why not have a param sent along with the url to decide what kind of resource will be used? something like `?resource=payment` at the end of the url that you check with `params[:resource] == 'payment'` and the use a conditional to determine what resource you will use / what view you render?